# Dracena Marginata leaves spots (orange and white)

Tags: dracaena

My Dracaena plant has started developing what appears to be two separate issues after I have repotted it (admittedly in the wrong time of the year - mid winter).

I've had it for close to 7 years now. I have repotted it previously and it didn't require much care: it was able to recover if I forgot to water it for a few days. It has been always located in a fairly sunny spot without any issues.

First, some leaves started to wilt turning yellowish (some may look like dry but it seems to be because of wilting).

Second, bright orange and brown spots started appearing as well. I've seen that those may be the result of exposure to direct sunlight, but it wasn't much of the problem for the last 7 years.

The first suspicion is that the soil is not a good fit for dracaena. Should I try a different soil?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about entire leaves going dry and falling, that's a normal life event for a dracena, it's just growing.

Your repotting time might have shocked it some, but I doubt it would have impacted a Dracena plant that much... they are tough. The culprits are usually:

1. Inconsistent watering: changing the amount or length of humidity or
   dryness in the soil, from one watering to the other. Some plants can get used to soil that is not optimally dry or wet, as long as the condition doesn't change too much too often.
2. Leaf spot disease

Have a look at this: https://bloomscape.com/houseplant-care-brown-spots-dracaena/